# Python simulator recommendation

Tags: python, visual-c++, codeblocks

Anyone has any python simulator to recommend? am new to python programming. is there any program similar to codeblocks for C++ programming? Thanks

Comment: I don't know what a "simulator" is. I think the term you are looking for is an IDE. In that case, you should try googling "Python IDE" and I'm sure you will find several options.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What IDE to use for Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be slightly confused over terminology.

The term "simulator" doesn't really mean much in the context of programming. A simulator is something which pretends to be some other platform so you can test code on it. For example, I might use an Android simulator or a Gameboy simulator on my computer so I can test code without having to transfer it all the time.

---

You might mean "IDE" instead. Codeblocks is an example of an IDE. It stands for "Integrated Development System". It combines a "compiler" (something which turns what you write into executable code) and a specialized "text editor" (a program which lets you write text). It also includes a wide variety of convenient features to make programming in C++ more easy.

Note that you technically don't need an IDE to write code. An IDE combines a compiler (or an interpreter, in the case of Python) with a text editor, and a bunch of extra features for convenience, but this is by no means "necessary", strictly speaking. All you need in order to write code is a text editor of some sort, and a compiler or interpreter.

For example, I typically use either Notepad++ or Vim to write my Python code, and run it directly from the command line.

---

Regardless, Python has a wide variety of IDEs you can look at. Here is [a comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81584/646543) of the most popular ones.

However, you don't necessarily need a fancy IDE to program in Python! If you just directly install Python, it comes with a simple IDE called "IDLE" which you can use to write and run Python code. If you're new to Python, I recommend you use IDLE for now, until you get the hang of things.

---

### tl;dr

To summarize:

- A **simulator** is a program that pretends to be some other kind of computer/platform. Simulators are used to test code.
- An **IDE** stands for "Integrated Development System" and is used to write and run code.
  It combines a compiler or interpreter with a text editor.
- There are many IDES for Python. Here is [a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81584/646543).
- However, I recommend you use IDLE, which is included by default when you install Python.

Comment: +1 for the thorough answer. If he reads this, it should help him out a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Codeblocks does have a plugin for Python: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Python_plugin . Though, I am not sure, how popular that is!

There was a similar discussion on SO: [What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)